# Adding an XSL build step to an Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, xslt

I'm quite new to Eclipse.

I have a fairly simple Android (Java) project being built in Eclipse, using the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

I also have a resource XML file (call it `target.xml`) that I wish to generate using XSL (`transform.xsl`) from another XML file (`source.xml`).

I've successfully installed the Eclipse [XSL Tools](http://wiki.eclipse.org/XSLT_Project). I've set up a Run Configuration, and I can build my `target.xml` file by, for example, right-clicking on my `transform.xml` file in the package explorer, and choosing Run->Run Configurations, then choosing that configuration under the "XSL" section of the configurations list and hitting "Run".

What I *want* is for this to happen automatically when I build/run/package up the Android project.

So, when I hit "play" to build and run the Android app on my attached device, Eclipse should know that if `source.xml` or `transform.xsl` have changed, it should first (or at least before the app packaging step) transform `source.xml` using `transform.xsl`, and thereby build `res/xml/target.xml`.

Is there a simple, elegant way to have this happen? In the old days, I'd just have added another couple of lines to my Makefile, but it seems like things have moved on...